# Python - extracting a list of sub strings

Tags: python, regex

How to extract a list of sub strings based on some patterns in python?

for example,

```
str = 'this {{is}} a sample {{text}}'.
```

expected result : a python list which contains 'is' and 'text'

Comment: Are you trying to extract only substrings that appear in double curly braces?

Comment: @Rafe Yes. I just need the string in that curly braces.

Comment: It is generally not a good idea to name a variable `string` as it is a commonly used Python module.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall("{{(.*?)}}", "this {{is}} a sample {{text}}")
['is', 'text']
```

Comment: @Siva: you'll need to escape the [s because they have a meaning within the regular expression: `re.findall(r"\\[\\[(.*?)]]", "this [[is]] a sample [[text]].")`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following:

```
res = re.findall("{{([^{}]*)}}", a)
print "a python list which contains %s and %s" % (res[0], res[1])
```

Cheers

Comment: You have to use `%r` instead of `%s` otherwise you won't get the quotes ;)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this. I would usually have put the format ('') in the printing string itself ( '%s' ) for example. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Assuming "some patterns" means "single words between double {}'s":

import re

re.findall('{{(\w*)}}', string)

Edit: Andrew Clark's answer implements "any sequence of characters at all between double {}'s"

Answer (score 1):

A regex-based solution is fine for your example, although I would recommend something more robust for more complicated input.

```
import re

def match_substrings(s):
    return re.findall(r"{{([^}]*)}}", s)
```

The regex from inside-out:

`[^}]` matches anything that's not a '}'
`([^}]*)` matches any number of non-} characters and groups them
`{{([^}]*)}}` puts the above inside double-braces

Without the parentheses above, `re.findall` would return the entire match (i.e. `['{{is}}', '{{text}}']`.  However, when the regex contains a group, findall will use that, instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression to match anything that occurs between `{{` and `}}`. Will that work for you?

Generally speaking, for tagging certain strings in a large body of text, a [suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) will be useful.